# Google Maps Polyline cannot drag corners

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox

I have been using Google maps for many years.  But I got tired of seeing the warning that I was requesting an obsolete version.  So I changed the invocation to:

```
 <script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=weekly&region=CA&key=*****&callback=initMap" 
        type="application/javascript">
```

But I have encountered a number of problems.  I am using Google Maps to support a genealogical service.  For example go to https://www.jamescobban.net/FamilyTree/Location.php?id=114191&lang=en and click on the Show Map button.  This shows the boundaries of this farm lot.  If this same URL is accessed by an registered user of the site the Show Map button displays an editable version of the map so the user can change the centre and the boundaries.

[image]

However I cannot drag the corners of the Polyline to correct the boundary.  I can add new points to the end of the Polyline, but I cannot correct the positions of the existing corners.  I am running Firefox 116.0.3.

```
var map             = null;

var path            = [];

var polyOptionsEdit = {strokeColor:     "red", 
                       strokeOpacity:   0.5,
                       strokeWeight:    2,
                       draggable:       true,   
                       editable:        true};
var boundary        = null;
var geocoder        = null;

function initMap()
{
    // support for displaying map and geocoding
    try {
        geocoder    = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        geocoder    = null;
    }
    map             = null;
}       // function initMap

window.initMap      = initMap;
boundary = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptionsEdit);
boundary.setPath(path);
```

Comment: If this `editable` option is only available to logged in/ registered users then we will be unable to test &/or debug this for ourselves. Is this phenomenon only exhibited in Firefox? Is it latest version? Does the same behaviour occur in a simplified version of your code? The `FamilyTree/Location.js` script still has `window.initMap = initMap;` - that said it is an unusual `initMap`  function anyway

Answer (score 0):

I have concluded that this was a temporary problem.  There were a number of other problems.  So I shut down Firefox and have had no issues since restarting.

Thank you to everyone who read my question.